# Is Joomla JRequest.getvar good sanitized against XSS?

Tags: xss

Can JRequest.getvar be used as an XSS Sanitizer or should I further clean the input??

Answer (score 0):

Use escape function in view.

```
<?php echo $this->escape($value);?>
```

This will do the xss cleaning. But it is availavle on the Jview

Do `$db->quote()` in the model to avoid  malicious code